# Filtering comma separated String in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, c#-2.0

I have a dynamic String value which may contain values like this

```
"Apple   ,Banana, , , ,  Mango  ,Strawberry  , "
```

I would like to filter this string like

```
"Apple,Banana,Mango,Strawberry".
```

I have tried with the following code and it works.

Is there any better approach to achieve the same in C#(.NET 2.0)?

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert "Comma Separated String" to "Comma Separated String"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="strWithComma">String having values separated by comma</param>
/// <returns>String separated with comma</returns>
private String CommaSeparatedString(String strWithComma)
{
    String rtn = String.Empty;

    List<String> newList= new List<string>();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strWithComma))
    {
        return rtn;
    }

    String[] strArray = strWithComma.Split(",".ToCharArray());


    if (strArray == null || strArray.Length == 0)
    {
        return rtn;
    }

    String tmpStr = String.Empty;
    String separator=String.Empty;
    foreach (String s in strArray)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            tmpStr =s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty);
            tmpStr = tmpStr.Trim();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmpStr))
            {
                newList.Add(tmpStr);
            }
        }
    }

    if (newList != null && newList.Count > 0)
    {

        rtn = String.Join(",", newList.ToArray());
    }
    return rtn;

}
```

Comment: For codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you have multiple words between commas?

Comment: @Rune, If there is any multiple words within comma, I would like to keep it as it is considering single space between words. Though I did not mention this in my post. Thank you so much for clarification.

Comment: You say you are using .NET 2.0 but what version of C#? (C# 3.5 uses .NET 2.0)

Comment: @Rune C#2.0 (Using Visual Studion 2005)

Comment: Thank you all for sharing your beautiful codes. I have some good ideas from all of you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the following should do the trick on any .NET version:

```
string[] TrimAll( string[] input )
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    foreach( var s in input )
        result.Add( s.Trim() );
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}

var delimiters = new [] { ",", "\t", Environment.NewLine };
string result = string.Join(",", TrimAll( input.Split( delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ) ) );
```

Edit: updated to deal with white-space, tabs and newline.

Comment: Unfortunately `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` will not remove entires consisting of only spaces.

Comment: What about white space and new line feed? Thanks.

Comment: @Konamiman true but just add whitespace to the array of delimiters and it works just like your answer (with the same problem for legit whitespace)

Comment: @ANeves did you actually take time to read the entire comment? konamimans suggested solution has the problem that it does not preserve white space between words as does this solution even if fixing the bug that konamiman points out all that (in a shorter version) is in the comment you refer too or am I missing your point?

Comment: @RuneFS [Will delete.] Sorry, you're right, I misread. Note to self, do not surf SO when tired. :(

Answer (score 7):

you can also use Regex:

```
string str = @"Apple   ,,Banana, , , ,  Mango  ,Strawberry  , ";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\s*,\s*)+", ",").TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: +1 for a working solution, even for the "multiple words" and NewLine scenarios

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = Regex.Replace(strWithComma, ",+", ",").TimEnd(',');
result = Regex.Replace(result, "\s+", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your items do not contain spaces:

```
private String CommaSeparatedString(String strWithComma)
{
    string[] tokens = strWithComma
        .Replace(" ", "")
        .Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return string.Join(",", tokens);
}
```

Now I'm not sure if C# 2.0 accepts the `new char[] {','}` syntax. If not, you can define the array somewhere else (as a class private member, for example).

Comment: the array syntax has been valid from 1.0 so that will not be a problem. You're code will not work with multiple words between commas

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w(?:(?!,| ).)*");
            var items = regex.Matches("Apple ,Banana, , , , Mango ,Strawberry , ").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
```

.NET 2.0 Version

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>();

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w(?:(?!,| ).)*");
            string str = "Apple ,Banana, , , , Mango ,Strawberry , ";
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(str);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                newList.Add(match.Value);
            }
```

Comment: This works... Of course you'd put strWithComma as the first arg in regex.Matches() and not the literal string as I did for an example...

Comment: Does it cover of removal of "new line feed"?

Comment: Yes. I've just tried it on `"Apple ,Banana, , , , Mango ,Strawberry , \nOrange"`   and it is fine

Comment: That pattern is basically `\w[^, ]*` (the only real difference is new lines). If you do want spaces in the tokens, you can use `[^\s,][^,]*?(?=\s*,|\s*$)` (you can probably simplify that, it looks like too much)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner:

```
var outputString = string.Join(",", inputString.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: Won't work when there's legit spaces between words and would be both cleaner and faster if you were splitting with " " and "," if spaces weren't allowed between words

Comment: In my code I also checked for new line feed. Will this code handle new line feed?

Comment: @Rune FS, Then it will be more complex than the original post. Consider this string: `"Apple   ,Banana, , Pineapple Orange , ,  Mango  ,Strawberry  , "`. Notice `, Pineapple Orange ,` and how the spaces are ambiguously placed. @Hoque, can you please update your question where necessary?

Comment: @hoque no at it won't allow withe space between words either

Comment: @AlexR. yes it will but if you read OPs answer to whether or not to preserve that kind of whitespace he says "yes it should be preserved"
And the original code does preserve that whitespace

Comment: The regex solution is the best one then. See @ojlovecd's answer.

Answer (score 1):

With no regular expressions, no splits and joins, trims, etc, O(n) time. StringBuilder is a very good class to work with strings.

**EDIT**
If the string it doesn't end with a letter it will add a comma. So an extra TrimEnd(',') is added

```
string strWithComma = ",Apple   ,Banana, , , ,  Mango  ,Strawberry  , \n John,";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var addComma = false;
foreach (var c in strWithComma )
{         
  if (Char.IsLetter(c)) // you might want to allow the dash also: example Anne-Marie
  {
    addComma = true;
    sb.Append(c);         
  }
  else
  {         
    if (addComma)
    {
      addComma = false;
      sb.Append(','); 
    }
  }  
}
string rtn = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: Seems interesting. Should give a try.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning** this method will only apply for C# 3.0 or higher. Sorry guys didnt read the question well enough

This will work but it can be done much easier like:

```
string input = "apple,banana,, \n,test\n, ,juice";

var parts = from part in input.Split(',')
            let trimmedPart = part.Replace("\n", "")
            where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(trimmedPart)
            select trimmedPart;

string result = string.Join(",", parts);
```